# doing mapping for following hardwares?

Tags: navigation, rplidar, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello

i have following components

1. Rplidar A1
2. SparkFun 9DoF Razor IMU M0
3. rotarary incremental encoders
4. differential drive robot
   5.ubuntu 16.04 with kinetic

im trying to do SLAM and i dont know which is good option for me with above hardwares , if i use gmapping can i fuse Imu and encoders or can i do gmapping only with encoders ?
should i need to buy ?
is there any other good mapping options ??

please guide me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333158/doing-mapping-for-following-hardwares-?/) by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at [ndt_fuser](http://wiki.ros.org/perception_oru/Tutorials/Using%20NDT%20Fuser%20to%20create%20an%20NDT%20map), you can feed this information about odometry and that will help in mapping. To get odometry with IMU and encoder, you can use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization).

NOTE: You cannot use your encoder data directly for robot_localization. You will need to convert it into a twist message or Odometry message.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on 2019-09-17**:
what about gmapping ?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-09-17**:
For gmapping to work you need to provide odom->base_link transform that comes from robot_localization. In short if this transform is available you can use gmapping and it should output map.